# How to find ODE , with constant-coefficient ,homogeneous , with minmum power such that $y_1(x) = xe^x$, $ y_2(x) = \sin^2(x)$ is soultions for it.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

> Find ODE , with constant-coefficient ,homogeneous , with minmum power,linear  such that  $y_1(x) = xe^x$, $ y_2(x) = \sin^2(x)$ is soultions for it.

how can one construct such ODE ?

> my trial :

by finding the **roots of the unique polynomal** for the Homogeneous ODE :

since  $y_1(x) = xe^x$ is solution $\rightarrow$ $(r-1)(r-1)$

since $ y_2(x) = \sin^2(x)$ is solution we rewrite as $ y_2(x) = \frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}$ so $ 1 , \cos(2x)$ is solutions .

we then write $(r)(r^2 + 4)$ so our polynomal is :

$F(r) = (r-1)(r-1)(r)(r^2+4)$ after simplfying :

$F(r) = r^5 - 2r^4 + 5r^3 - 8r^2 + 4r$

so $ y^{(5)}-2y^{(4)}+5y^{'''}-8y^{''}+4y^{'} = 0 $ is our ODE.

not sure if the solution is right , also not sure if its the minimum powers. much thanks for help

Comment: That's the correct answer...

Comment: You need to word it a little differently to transform it into a rigorous answer. Start with assuming the minimal equation has characteristic polynomial $p(r).$ Then, show that $p(r)$ must be divisible by the two polynomials you have found and this would conclude the proof.

Comment: thank you both , but how can one be sure that this ODE has minimum powers of $ ''''' $

Comment: Maybe by showing that all solutions are linearly independent of each other? So you can conclude that you actually need all your factors since you cannot write of of these in terms of another one.

Comment: It's more of an algebra concept. $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a Unique Factorization Domain, which basically means that if a polynomial is divisible by bunch of other polynomials that are pairwise - relatively prime, then it has to be divisible by the product of all divisors. But if this is ODE class then I doubt you need to provide proof of this fact. Just mention it.

Comment: @dezdichado Can this argumentation be expanded to for example $\mathbb R[x]$? Hence it is more of an coincidence that all roots of the charateristic polynomial are integers.

Comment: @mrtaurho yes of course. $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, so it is obviously a UFD. In general, if $R$ is a UFD, then $R[x]$ is also UFD.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\mathcal{D}$ linear we have

$$
\mathcal{D}y_1 = 0\\
\mathcal{D}y_2 = 0
$$

and

$$
\mathcal{D}(y_1+y_2) = \mathcal{D}y_1 +\mathcal{D}y_2 = 0 
$$

then $y = y_1+y_2$ satisfies as well the DE. Considering now the more general problem with $\mathcal{D}$ invertible

$$
\mathcal{D}(y) = u\Rightarrow y = \mathcal{D}^{-1}u
$$

or using the Laplace transform

$$
Y(s) = \mathcal{L}\left(xe^x+\sin^2 x\right) = \frac{2}{s \left(s^2+4\right)}+\frac{1}{(s-1)^2} = \frac{s^3+2 s^2+2}{(s-1)^2 s \left(s^2+4\right)}=G(s) U(s)
$$

making now $u = \delta(t)$ associated to initial conditions we have

$$
G(s) = \mathcal{L}\left(\mathcal{D}^{-1}\right)
$$

hence

$$
\mathcal{D} = \partial^{(5)}_t-2\partial^{(4)}_t+5\partial^{(3)}_t-8\partial^{(2)}_t+4\partial_t
$$

so your answer is correct.